# php fopen in ubuntu file systen

Tags: php, path, download, ubuntu-12.04

I want to download a file using php. Everything is working fine on windows, but when I try to run the same php code on my ubuntu 12.04 just an empty file gets downloaded without any content. When I try to run the following code:

```
    <?php
        $filename = '/root/my_folder/filename.pdf';
        if(file_exists($filename))
            $f = fopen( '/root/my_folder/filename.pdf', 'r') or exit('unable to open file');
        else
            echo 'file does not exists';
    ?>
```

It always display the 'file does not exists'. Is the issue with setting path to my folder ?
Can anyone help me with this. I'm new in Ubuntu. Thanks

Comment: your apache user does not hae the permission to access /root/myfolder/filename.pdf . You will have to either add apache user to the group that is accessing /root/myfolder or change the ownership of filename.pdf or change the permissions on /root/myfolder

Comment: I've given permissions to myfolder by chmod -R 777 /root/myfolder

Comment: is it myfolder or my_folder ? just checking if it is a typo

Comment: No Satya.. my folder is just a ref name.. I'm using the correct folder and file names..

Comment: Thanks @satya. The issue was with permissions only. I was giving permissions to /root/myfolder, but the /root itself didn't had enough permissions to open a file..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `apache` user does not hae the permission to access `/root/myfolder/filename.pdf` . You will have to either add `apache` user to the group that is accessing `/root/myfolder` or `change the ownership` of `filename.pdf` or change the permissions on `/root/myfolder`

Comment: what permission type should give to `/root/myfolder`?